# Documents not inserting to mongoDB?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, list, upsert, uniq

I've set up a mongoDB on an Ubuntu AWS instance. I also have something like 920 files ranging in size from 5Mb to 2Gb or so.

Once each unzipped text file is uniq'd with `uniq`, I run the following script to insert them into the DB:

```
require 'mongo'
require 'bson'

Mongo::Logger.logger.level = ::Logger::FATAL
puts "Working..."
db = Mongo::Client.new([ 'localhost:27017' ], :database => 'supers')
coll = db[:hashes]
# suppressors = File.open('_combined.txt')
suppressors = Dir['./_uniqued_*.txt']
count = suppressors.count
puts "Found #{count}"
suppressors.each_with_index do |fileroute, i|
  suppressor = File.open(fileroute, 'r')
  percentage = ((i+1) / count.to_f * 100).round(2)
  puts "Working on `#{fileroute}` (#{i+1}/#{count} - #{percentage})"
  c = 0
  suppressor.each_line do |hash|
    c+=1
    coll.update_one({ :_id => hash }, { :$inc => { :count => 1 } }, { upsert: true} )  
    puts "Processed 50k records for #{fileroute}" if c % 50_000 == 0  
  end
end
```

The idea is, if the record already exists, the `$inc` will set the count to 2 or 3 so I'll be able to find all the duplicates by running a query on the DB later.

I connected to the instance via RoboMongo and at first every time I refreshed the following query:

`db.getCollection('hashes').count({})`

I'd see that it was filling up the DB very quickly. There's lots of files but I figured I'd leave it overnight.

[image]

However after some time the result got stuck at `3788104`. I was worried there was some hard size limit (`df` says I'm only using 35% of the HDD space)

#### Is there something in the config file which automatically limits the amount of records which can be inserted or something?

PS: is it just me or is either `upsert` or `.each_line` incredibly slow?

Comment: don't know, but maybe you can track which files were uploaded and running the script skips those.

Comment: There is no limit as far as i know. I would add some xtra console logging to see on which entry in de file it's failing, maybe there is something in there which wrecks your code.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB's update model is based on write concerns, meaning that calling the function `updateOne` alone is not a guarantee for success.

If the version of MongoDB is at least 2.6, the function `updateOne` will return a document with information about any errors. If the version of MongoDB is older, an explicit call of the `getLastError` command will return the document with possible errors.

If the database does not contain all desired documents, it is likely that this returned document will contain errors.

In both cases, the write concern can be adjusted to the desired level, i.e., gives control about how many mongo instances must have propagated the change for it to be considered a success.

(Note: I am not familiar with the Ruby driver, this is assuming it behaves like the shell).